# Quick Tests in Swift Succeeding when failing

Tags: ios, swift, quick-nimble

I am trying to run Quick tests with Nimble on a swift project for BDD testing. I am installing these using cocoapods with the following podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

use_frameworks!

target ‘jollyday.iOS’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '3.0.0-beta.3'
end

target ‘jollyday.iOSTests’ do
    pod 'Quick', '~> 0.6.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '2.0.0-rc.3'
end
```

However when I run my tests they are passing all the time, no matter what my test is, here is the following test that I am running and it just passes every time:

```
import Quick
import Nimble

class DogSpec : QuickSpec {
    override func spec(){
        describe("Test Suite") {

            it("Test 1") {
                expect(1 + 1).to(equal(3))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only time it works is if I close the project down, then open it again.  The first time I run the test after this, the test returns the correct result whether it should pass or fail. After this, the test will continually succeed.

Has anyone seen this error before? or does anyone know of anything else I can clear instead of having to close my whole project down every time?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey were you able to fix this ? If so would love to hear how you did this !